# Transliteration on iOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, api, transliteration

Is it possible to use the [Google Transliterate API](http://code.google.com/apis/language/transliterate/overview.html) on iOS particularly and/or Android?

The key here is to be able to let users type non-english (transliterated from english) text anywhere in any regular text field without opening any app and copy/paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7619

This might be helpful